# bootstrap stylesheet are loaded twice

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In chrome network I can see what bootstrap.min.css was loaded twice.
Can anybody explain me why? v.57 on win 8.1
[image: chrome network]

Comment: This is occurring with the exact html document you included in your question?

Comment: Yes, I try just now, this html code on my home PC (also win 8.1 and Chrome 57), and get same problem: bootstrap.min.css was loaded twice.

Comment: The CSS link's integrity attribute is what's making it load twice, I'm still trying to find out why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found some info about the issue [here](https://medium.com/reloading/preload-prefetch-and-priorities-in-chrome-776165961bbf).

> The `integrity` attribute for link elements has not yet been implemented and there’s an open spec issue about it. This means the presence of any integrity metadata will currently discard preloaded resources. In the wild, it can also result in duplicate requests where you have to make a trade-off between security and performance.

Comment: So should I keep the intergrity tag? Or not use it for now?

Comment: It's up to you. It doesn't look like there's a lot going on about resolving the issues with the attribute so this bug will probably be around for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear this is related to integrity tags. With or without them I see multiple loads of bootstrap.min.css in Firefox's Web Dev Network pane.

This seems to be due to the Bootstrap JS including a separate call to it. Though for performance reasons it's for the best to persist the direct load of the CSS.